# Count the number of lines in an Excel File

Tags: php, wordpress, excel, count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Efficiently counting the number of lines of a text file. (200mb+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162497/efficiently-counting-the-number-of-lines-of-a-text-file-200mb)
>   [How do I determine the end of the file using PHPExcel library in chunk loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972404/how-do-i-determine-the-end-of-the-file-using-phpexcel-library-in-chunk-loop)

I can't seem  to get this to work in PHP

I'm trying to count the number of lines in an uploaded EXcel file

Here is what I have but it always multiplies this by two and I want to remove the first row because it is just headers, please help:

```
$countthelines= count(file($file)) -1;
```

Comment: Excel files aren't text files, they're binary blobs. Are you confusing it with a CSV file perhaps?

Comment: Possibly but what I want to do is count the number of lines in an EXCEL file not CSV so any help would be appreciated

Comment: If your excel file just contains a single table you can convert your file to csv without losing data.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your Excel file to a CSV file and try something like this:

```
$countthelines = count(file($file, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)) - 1;
```

Comment: But it has to be an Excel file not a CSV, any way to do that or do an inline conversion into a CSV?