# How to extend Allowed memory size in PHPExcel Library?

Tags: phpexcel

I want to extend the allowed memory size. Currently my excel downloads are not downloading it throws following error:

```
 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
 to allocate 32 bytes) in application/libraries/Excel/PHPExcel/Cell.php
 on line 839
```

Comment: Either increase the memory that your php.ini sets as the limit;  or try using cell caching - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817651/phpexcel-runs-out-of-256-512-and-also-1024mb-of-ram/4817729

Answer (score 0):

Increase memory limit in your php:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

After this the memory limit will be 1 GB.

Comment: This issue is not related to extending PHP memory size. Issue is related to Extending PHPExcel memory. FYI, my php.ini file has 2GB memory limit.