# How to read a xls file using zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, xls

How to read a xls file using zend framework?

Is it possible to read a **xls** file(Excel) named `common.xls` using **Zend Spreadsheets**.

Comment: Is there any problem using plain php?

Comment: [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) is the best way to do it if you need precise control (like styles, formulas, etc).

Comment: @HappyApe: Yes, ofcourse i can use plain php. But how?

Comment: @JustinJohn - I tried posting some examples below - pls have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments you could use `[PHPExcel][1]`

```
//-----Create a reader, set some parameters and read in the file-----
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV');
$objReader->setDelimiter(’,’);
$objReader->setEnclosure('');
$objReader->setLineEnding("\r\n");
$objReader->setSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('path/to/commons.xls’);
```

Full tutorial 
http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/05/07/4606.aspx

Stackoverflow Qs that may help you -

[PHPExcel reader -- help required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792543/phpexcel-reader-help-required)

---

Or Have a look at [PHP Excel Reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/)

Example

```
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("common.xls",false);
```

> The simplest way to interact with an XLS file is to just dump it to
>   HTML for display in a browser. This method will generate a table with
>   inline CSS and all available formatting.

```
$data->dump($row_numbers=false,$col_letters=false,$sheet=0,$table_class='excel')
```

Hope this helps.